# Integrating Compass to generator-webapp error

Tags: yeoman, compass, yeoman-generator

I followed the tutorial in the link: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/compass.md And then I got the following error. What am I wrong here? Please help!

Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss.

Load paths: /Users/lazhcm10354/Documents/OpenHouseWrapper/openhouse/bower_components Compass::SpriteImporter /Users/lazhcm10354/Documents/OpenHouseWrapper/openhouse/app/styles /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets on line 4 of /Users/lazhcm10354/Documents/OpenHouseWrapper/openhouse/app/styles/main.scss

1: $icon-font-path: "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/"; 2: 3: // bower:scss 4: @import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss"; 5: // endbower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the prl is cause of wrong path. 
Add ../to the path bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss

One thing, delete .sass_cache folder as well

Comment: Thanks for your help. Because my sass get from cache, so it doesn't affect to my changes.